# How to enable camelCase warning in VS Code [Dart]

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

It is shown as underlined when naming wrong while writing code in Android Studio. However, I did not see such a thing in VS Code. Is there a way to turn it on or is there no such feature?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are trying to 2 do things at once here.

First, dart has 2 lints rules that ensure your code is using `camelCase`

- [non_constant_identifier_names](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules#non_constant_identifier_names)
- [constant_identifier_names](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules#constant_identifier_names)

The rules are by default included in the recommended set of lint rules.

They prevent you from writting:

```dart
const PI = 3.14;
const kDefaultTimeout = 1000;
final URL_SCHEME = RegExp('^([a-z]+):');

class Dice {
  static final NUMBER_GENERATOR = Random();
}

var Item;

HttpRequest http_request;

ALIGN(clearItems) {
  // ...
}
```

But they don't prevent you from writing

```dart
var userage;
var familyname;
var studentnumber;
```

because those names verify the `camelCase` regexp.

- `userAge` is a combination of 2 words ("user" and "age").
- `userage` implies your variable is one single word ("userage"). This word doesn't exist in English but dart doesn't know that.

What you want now is to verify the spelling of your variables.

You can install the VSCode extension [`cSpell`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker) for that and it will verify that each sub-words of a variable exist and are properly spelled.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Spell checker is working but there is a problem it is detecting some words incorrectly. For example, it shows code like "GetxController" and "Icons.gamepad" as misspellings. I guess there is no way to fix this, thanks again for your help.

Comment: You can add those words into the cSpell dictionnary

Answer (score 0):

Install Camel Case Navigation Extensions

Download from [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maptz.camelcasenavigation) or Go to Extensions or search "Camel Case Navigation"